# onItemClick pass item id to intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onitemclick

I'm printing the right id out from the first intent but not sending to it the second intent properly.

first intent on item click:
(For later viewers this question has been updated with the correct answer):

```
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(videoChannelActivity.this,
                    PlayVideoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("videoId", l);
            System.out.println("video id intent1 = " + l);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

log: `05-08 17:40:40.505: I/System.out(13938): video id intent 1: 2`

second intent on create:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final VideoView videoView;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);

    Bundle extras;
    long videoLong;

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            videoLong = 0;
        } else {
            videoLong = extras.getLong("videoId");
            System.out.println("video id intent 2 =  " + videoLong);
        }
    }
```

log: `05-08 17:46:19.166: I/System.out(14382): video id intent 2 =  null`

Comment: You put long and trying to get string... first :P

Comment: You're putting in a Long in your first activity and you are retrieving a String. Change the `extras.getString(...`.

Comment: `videoLong = (Long) null` this isn't going to work, gonna need to handle it in a different fashion, for example `videoLong = 0`; or as Matej suggested, use `Long videoLong;`, just keep in mind if the value isn't found in `extras.getLong("videoId")` it will return 0, not null. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getLong(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**l** is type of **long** ...

so you need to extract long instead of String like

```
 videoLong = extras.getLong("videoId");
```

so the full implementation of second intent is

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final VideoView videoView;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);

    Bundle extras;
    Long videoLong;

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            videoLong= null;
        } else {
            videoLong= extras.getLong("videoId");
            System.out.println("video id intent 2 =  " + videoLong);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No problem, good luck with Android programming :-) . Please if you consider my answer as helpfull , vote it up or mark it as correct. Thank you very much :)

Comment: `videoLong= null` long cannot be null, gonna need to handle in another fashion

Comment: Yes , i forgot ... primitive data types cannot be null, you need to use a wrapper class *Long*, answer edited :P ...

Comment: also might want to consider using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getLong(java.lang.String,%20long) with a different defaultValue if 0 isn't an acceptable default

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `long` as an extra but trying to read it as a `String.`